# Is there a way to check the output from a Data Loader will match the input to a model?

Tags: pytorch-dataloader

ERROR IS - RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (896x28 and 784x512)

**Background:** Image classification problem with data of dimensions `(60000, 28, 28)`. Labels have been encoded into dimensions `(60000, 10)`. Data Class has been created:

```
import torch 
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader , TensorDataset, Dataset

class image_Data_Class(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_train, y_train):
      super().__init__()
      self.x = torch.from_numpy(x_train)
      self.y = torch.from_numpy(y_train)
      self.y = self.y.type(torch.LongTensor)
      self.len = self.x.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
      return self.x[index], self.y[index]
   
    def __len__(self):
      return self.len

## Create a Data Loader for use in the training of the model 

BATCH_SIZE = 32 ## as a start for modelling purposes 

img_data = image_Data_Class(x_train, y_train)
train_loader = DataLoader(img_data, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True)
```

When I run:

```
print(f"x_train is : {img_data.x.shape}, y_train is : {img_data.y.shape}")
```

The output is: `x_train is : torch.Size([60000, 28, 28]), y_train is : torch.Size([60000, 10])`

**Issue**: When I run it in the following training model

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 3 # to start with
losses = []

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        ## Initialise gradients 
        optimiser.zero_grad()

        # forward pass
        y_pred = model(x)

        # compute the loss 
        loss = loss_func(y_pred, y)

        ## backward pass
        loss.backward()

        ## update weights 
        optimiser.step()
        print(loss)
    losses.append(float(loss.data.detach().numpy()))
```

I get the following error:
`RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (896x28 and 784x512)`

The math works out that the batch size (32) is being multiplied by the first dimension of the training data (28) to give...896. Is this a coincidence??

I have tried:
`view() // squeeze()` in the model but this results in an index error or a very large input dimension.

Model Class below for reference.

```
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

class nn_Multiclass_Model(nn.Module):
    #lin1, lin2, 
    def __init__(self, NUM_FEATURES, NUM_CLASSES, NUM_HIDDEN_FEATURES):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(NUM_FEATURES, NUM_HIDDEN_FEATURES)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(NUM_HIDDEN_FEATURES, NUM_CLASSES)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.lin2(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

I'm sure it's something elementary but I can't find it after looking for some time. Thx